# Reading in the First Line from a .txt File, Removnig it from the .txt., and Sliding all of the Other Lines Up by 1 Unit

Tags: perl

I have a .txt file in which each line is only one element.  As the subject suggests, I'd like to input the first row from the .txt.  Then, I'd like to remove it from the .txt file as soon as I've inputted it.  At the same time, I'd like to then slide each element up by one row such that the former second row element becomes the new first row.

I'm not quite sure how to proceed beyond:  open( my $l,  '<', 'Input.txt' ) or die "Can not open Input.txt: $!";

Comment: Given your question and some of your comments, it looks like you might be well served learning a little bit about Perl too. I recommend the excellent (and free electronically!) [Modern Perl Book](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use strict;

if ($#ARGV)
{
    print "\nUsage: test.pl Filename\n\n";
    exit();
}

my $f;
if (open($f, $ARGV[0]))
{
    print scalar(<$f>);

    my $s = join('', <$f>);
    close($f);

    if (open($f, '>', $ARGV[0]))
    {
        print $f $s;
        close($f);
    }
}
else print "\nCan't open input file $ARGV[0]\n\n";
```

or sub

```
sub slideFile($)
{
    my $filename = shift();

    my $f;
    if (open($f, $filename))
    {
        <$f>;

        my $s = join('', <$f>);
        close($f);

        if (open($f, '>', $filename))
        {
            print $f $s;
            close($f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is ARGV the name of the .txt ?

Comment: why didn't you need the line that the OP had: open( my $l, '<', 'Input.txt' ) or die "Can not open Input.txt: $!"

Comment: Ok, i just added last line for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!!  I really appreciate your help.  It is not clear to me either what the name of the .txt is.  So what exactly should I save my .txt as?

Comment: oh.  could it not be done that way?  this is going to be a few lines of code that i add to a much larger program . . . so i'm just wondering what few lines of code will achieve this goal . . .

Comment: Put code from `my $f;` to file and replace `$ARGV[0]` with filename.

Comment: so instead of $filename denoting filename.txt ?

Comment: Put sub in your code and call like `slideFile("filename.txt");`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove from a file. You can simply read every byte that follows and write them back at the earlier position. This is expensive, but easy to do with Tie::File.

Comment: Like I said, it will copy the entire contents of the file earlier into the file every time you remove the current first line. (It use a cache in memory to speed things up.)

Comment: Do you have an example?  How straight forward is it to apply Tie::File to the problem at hand?

Comment: You're asking me how to remove the first element of an array? `shift(@tied);`

Comment: I, at least, would appreciate that because I have no idea how to implement that.

Comment: Implement what? It's just `shift(@tied);`. Did you even look up [Tie::File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie::File)???

Answer (score 2):

When you use `Tie::File`, you can *tie* a file to an `@array` so that each element in the array corresponds to a line in the file.

In the following example, the `shift` operator removes the first element from `@lines` and assigns it to `$first_line`. Since `@lines` is tied to `file.txt` the first row in that file is also removed.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', 'file.txt' or die $!;

my $first_line = shift @lines;

print "first line WAS: $first_line\n";

untie @lines;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp;

my $i = 0;
write_file $ARGV[0], grep $i++, read_file $ARGV[0];
```

Usage: `perl script.pl inFile`

The script uses [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/~uri/File-Slurp-9999.19/lib/File/Slurp.pm) in list context, and `grep` which allows the lines to pass only if `$i` isn't zero, so the first line is omitted, and lines 2 .. n are written back to the file.

Hope this helps!